# Moq can Mock HubConnection but RhinoMocks can't?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, signalr, moq, rhino-mocks

I'm looking at the [unit tests](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/tests/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Tests/Client/HubProxyFacts.cs) for SignalR and noticed one of the tests uses Moq to create a mock HubConnection:

```
[Fact]
public void HubCallbackClearedOnFailedInvocation()
{
    var connection = new Mock<HubConnection>("http://foo");
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    tcs.TrySetCanceled();

    connection.Setup(c => c.Send(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(tcs.Task);

    var hubProxy = new HubProxy(connection.Object, "foo");

    var aggEx = Assert.Throws<AggregateException>(() => { hubProxy.Invoke("foo", "arg1").Wait(); });
    var ex = aggEx.Unwrap();

    Assert.IsType(typeof(TaskCanceledException), ex);

    Assert.Equal(connection.Object._callbacks.Count, 0);
}
```

However, when I try and do the same with a slightly different mocking framework, RhinoMocks, it complains that the method isn't virtual:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldCreateBrokerWithHubConnection()
{
    //Arrange
    var url = "http://localhost6790";
    var hubProxy = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IHubProxy>();
    var hubConnection = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HubConnection>(url);
    hubConnection.(c => c.CreateHubProxy("ArtemisClientHub")).Return(hubProxy);

    ... (more code)
 }
```

`System.InvalidOperationException : Invalid call, the last call has been used or no call has been made (make sure that you are calling a virtual (C#) / Overridable (VB) method).`

Is this just a shortcoming of RhinoMocks compared to a newer library like Moq?

Comment: Argh, I think the issue is that `Send` is, indeed, overridable. Whereas `CreateHubProxy` isn't. I was just comparing apples to oranges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My tip is to use the none concrete types from your code and inject the   concrete types using a Ioc.  The signalr dot net client however is missing a DependencyResolver unlike the server. I rolled my own to get around this,  you can check out the code here (But in your case you can use any Ioc like Ninject,  autofac etc)

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.DotNet/Bootstrap/DependencyResolver.cs

The hub connection and proxy  is a bit hard to abstract since you are dependent on the concrete types to create the proxy.  I solved it with abstracting the creation of the hub proxy to a factory interface that returns a IHubProxy that can be easily mocked.

Look here
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.DotNet/Bootstrap/Factories/HubProxyFactory.cs

All examples are taken from my dot net client for this library 
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy

Comment: This is a very good comment that gets to the root of my issue: getting rid of the direct dependency on HubConnection. However, having a HubConnection around is useful because you can check your connection state and retry connecting if it fails to initialize properly the first time. Any thoughts on this, given your example?

Comment: Well if IHubProxy does not provide the correct members then you  have to crate your own interface that abstracts the hub proxy with the correct members

Comment: Yep, I ended up creating my own 'wrapper' for the class: https://gist.github.com/killnine/05c47128735201c32ddc. May package this up later. I wish SignalR handled this more gracefully by default.